# Windows 10: Poor Performance for Playing Game & Screen Capture

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card, performance, screen-capture

I hope this is the best StackExchange site to ask questions about optimizing system performance. If not, I apologize, & please direct me to the appropriate site.

My current system is one of the best I have ever had. It is not the best gaming system, but I am not running high end games. The issue comes when I record/capture videos of some games that I play. I end up with choppy/jumpy/jittery videos. As it happens with multiple games & recording software, I am concluding that there is some issue with the system's performance, as opposed to it being the fault of a specific app.

My system is an [HP Pavilion 24-b217c](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c05381021). I am running Windows 10 64-bit:

[image: System Information]

It has two graphics chips: Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 & NVIDIA GeForce 930MX. The Intel chip uses 1GB of system memory & the NVIDIA chip has 2GB of its own dedicated memory.

GPUs info:

[image: GPUs Information]

By default, apps use the Intel chip. But I can change that for each individual app in graphics settings: "Power saving" uses the Intel. Setting to "High performance" tells the system to use the NVIDIA chip for the app when it is launched:

[image: App GPU Settings]

I have also disabled most system visual effects settings:

[image: Visual Effects Settings]

The software that I am currently using to capture my screen is [Captura](https://mathewsachin.github.io/Captura/). I have also tried [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) & the command line [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) with the same or similar results (Note: all these apps are FFmpeg/libav-based). I have also tested the built-in Xbox Game Bar that comes with Windows 10. It seems to suffer less from jitter, but the game itself suffers & is captured in the video, albeit less often. Also, I haven't found any settings in the Xbox Game Bar to change capture quality or resolution, which I absolutely want.

The games that I am playing are 2D platformers, such as [Mega Man Unlimited](http://megaphilx.com/index.php/home/games/mega-man-unlimited/), [Mega Man Rock Force](http://megamanrockforce.com/rockforcemain.html), [Mega Man Rock N Roll](https://dennisengelhard.com/rock-n-roll/), & [Street Fighter X Megaman](http://megaman.capcom.com/sfxmm/). Changing which GPU is used does not appear to change performance for any of these games.

Also, I am running [COMODO Internet Security](https://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/free-internet-security.php). I have tried shutting this off when I record, but it doesn't seem to make a differenece.

The issue isn't consistent. At times my video will be choppy, & other times not. I am wondering if it is being caused by I/O speed, either the recording software writing to the hard drive or some other background application. But I think perhaps it is *not* directly related to the recording software as I sometimes get choppy gameplay even if I am not recording. It does appear that after restarting my system, I do get a bit better performance for a period.

According to the task manager, about 38% of my CPU is being used, 49% of system memory, 13% of the Intel GPU, & 22% of the NVIDIA GeForce GPU during gameplay & recording. That is with a browser window with multiple tabs & a text editor open (which usually are not when I am recording) & no other foreground apps. So those system resources seem to be okay:

[image]

I'm curious if the issue I am having is specific to my system or if there are any known issues with Windows 10 performance that I am unaware of & things I can do to try & fix it. I am also open to screen capture software suggestions. I prefer open source solutions but am willing to try out others. It appears that most of the actively developed open source screen capturing software that I have found is based on FFmpeg/libav.

**--- Edit ---**

I should note that on older systems with less resources, I haven't had near as many problems capturing gameplay in the past as I do with this one.

Comment: You don't really have the system to stream/record gameplay, but which drive, are you creating the files on?

Comment: Which hard drive? I only have one drive. It has a recovery (D) partition, but I am recording to the C partition.

Comment: Also for clarification, I'm not live streaming, just recording straight to disk.

Comment: On another note, it seems ridiculous that my system is using up 50% of 12GB of RAM. It seems no matter how much I upgrade to a system with more RAM, Windows still wants to use at least 50% of it.

Comment: @Ramhound: Sorry, when you asked "which drive", I assumed you meant which physical drive. But I see now that you were looking at my "C:" & "D:" drives from the task manager. Yes, I am recording to C:. D: is the recovery partition.

Comment: Mechanical or SSD?

Comment: What processes use up most of the resources?

Comment: @Ramhound: Mechanical.

Comment: @dan1st: The game & Captura are using the most CPU. The game, Captura, & Google Drive Sync are using the most RAM. I'm going to shut down Sync. I thought it was idle while I wasn't updating files in its directory. Will see if it improves anything.

Comment: Closed Sync & uninstalled Comodo (turns out there were still some background processes running), but issue remains. The rest of the processes using up resources are system processes/services.

Comment: I now have gone through the system & disabled/removed many non-essential apps & services. Problem still hasn't been solved. But it appears that I might be getting better results as it seems to happen less often (written soon after a system restart, so we will see if results persist).

Comment: I take it back, it's happening just as often. Even with a fresh defragmentation.